# ¿Iniciar sesion con email o username en el mismo campo, Laravel API?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esta funcion que me ayuda a iniciar sesion con email pero quiero implementar que sea con email o username en el mismo campo, como le puedo hacer?

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
}
```

Comment: ¿el mismo campo para ambos? es una pésima idea.

Comment: Aunque hay opiniones sobre si es buena práctica o no, debes tener bien definido el modelo de usuario. Si deseas realizar el `login` usando el correo o el nombre de usuario en un solo campo, y dejar que el usuario decida usar uno u otro, tu método de validación debe ser capaz de diferenciar que se ha usado un correo o un nombre de usuario. Por otro lado, los nombres de usuario deben tener como requisito al menos lo siguiente: "No se permite el carácter @", además debes agregar el `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` al campo de nombre de usuario en la BD. Con eso y tu método para diferenciarlos tienes. Saludos

Comment: Es una pésima idea, los campos en la base de datos deben almacenar información de un solo tipo, no conozco el primer programador con suficiente experiencia o conocimiento que afirme lo contrario.

Comment: a lo mejor no me di a entender, pero yo quiero que tengan inicio de sesion como la pagina gitlab, te da a eligir entre poner username o email. pero el username y el email se guardan en una columna diferente ,, quiero que al momento de que en el input pongan "adrian" y su password , o "adrian@blabla" y su password  tenga acceso

Comment: Se entendió, pero va depender de muchas cosas... Recordar que el input para el mail está validado **para un mail**... Permitir que un campo acepte, además de un mail una cadena de texto cualquiera, invalidaria el formato del mail y no evitaría que el  usuario verifique que el mail sea escrito correctamente, y viceversa...  Luego de corregir esto la lógica vendrá de como hagas la consulta en la base de datos... @MauricioContreras te dio un comentario muy valido...

Comment: Creo que se puede, no me parece una mala idea. Lo que no me cierra de esta pregunta es que no nos dices qué has probado. Acabo de hacer una búsqueda y me devolvió muchos tutoriales (incluso en [español](https://medium.com/@juanrincn/laravel-5-5-5-4-5-3-iniciar-sesi%C3%B3n-con-nombre-de-usuario-o-email-con-el-mismo-input-campo-6ed6ea2c1579)) y respuestas de [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53574802/7498116) (aunque éstas, sí, en inglés). Entonces, propongo que pruebes algo, y edites  la pregunta con un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email_username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email_username)
        ->orWhere('username', $request->email_username)
        ->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))
        ->first();
    if(!$user)){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    }
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
}
```

Comment: Añade una explicación a tu código; pues poner solo un script se considera de baja calidad